# GoogleMaps custom marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Is it possible to create your own marker with your own styles? That is, change the background, change the radius, add a shadow, etc. All I got was to change the opacity and replace it with an icon.

https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.com/#marker

```
<Marker
        onLoad={onLoad}
        position={position}
        onClick={() => console.log(343)}
        // icon='/static/media/truck.0055f2f3.svg'
        opacity={.5}
      />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon IS the custom marker, everything you want to change about the marker you have to do to the icon. Since you have an svg it shouldn't be too hard to style.

[Custom marker example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom)

Comment: well, I thought that I can change it like a regular div with styles

Comment: then it turns out I need to draw some icons and depending on the events on the map change the path and insert the icon I need?

Comment: You can apply styles to svgs 

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/